# How to refresh/invalidate NSCursor?

Tags: objective-c, appkit

When I update my cursor rect with resetCursorRects on my custom view, it correctly updates the cursor, as long as the user moves out of the rect, then back in. Is there a way where I can get the NSCursor to refresh without the user having to mouse out and back in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to call your `NSWindow`'s

`invalidateCursorRectsForView:`

method.